# WPA-Supplicant goes through the motions of connecting without connecting

Tags: wireless-adapter, wpa-supplicant

I dug out an old Raspbery Pi B+ and tried to setup a wifi connection with a Realtek USB wifi stick. Since there were no drivers I compiled a driver (https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver). This seems to have worked. Now, when I try to connect to a wireless network with wpa-supplicant

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d
```

it first prompts me to delete /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0

```
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

I believe this happens because it tries to setup wlan0 on reboot.
After having deleted the file, everything seems to work.
It finds my Network, does some Handshakes, and seems to connect.

```
wlan0: State: GROUP_HANDSHAKE -> COMPLETED
wlan0: Radio work 'connect'@0x105cb10 done in 0.845330 seconds
wlan0: radio_work_free('connect'@0x105cb10): num_active_works --> 0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=1
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=1
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATING
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state SUCCESS
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Authorized
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
EAPOL authentication completed - result=SUCCESS
```

After this, there are a few more lines

```
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'wlan0' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
Received 525 bytes of scan results (2 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 3
BSS: last_scan_res_used=2/32
wlan0: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
WPS: AP cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 type 0 added
WPS: AP[0] cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
wlan0: Scan results matching the currently selected network
wlan0: 1: cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 freq=2442 level=30 snr=30 est_throughput=16000
wlan0: Selecting BSS from priority group 0
wlan0: 0: 30:de:4b:e2:47:92 ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=48 freq=2417
wlan0:    skip - SSID not known
wlan0: 1: cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 ssid='Seg4' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=30 freq=2442 wps
wlan0:    selected based on RSN IE
wlan0:    selected BSS cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08 ssid='Seg4'
EAPOL: startWhen --> 0
EAPOL: disable timer tick
```

Then, it waits for a few seconds, and just redoes the same thing. How do I get WPA-Supplicant to actually connect me to to the wireless network?

EDIT:
My wpa-supplicant file contains

```
 ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
 update_config=1
 country=DE
 
 network={
         ssid="Seg4"
         psk="<password>"
         scan_ssid=1
 }
```

EDIT 2:
I just saw the scan_ssid=1 and wondered if that might be the issue, so I tried without. Like this, it does not repeat the whole connecting routine, and just periodically shows scan results like above. In ifconfig, i still don't get assigned an ip-address.

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether a6:cb:84:bf:52:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 65  bytes 25582 (24.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 133  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2  bytes 1152 (1.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Edit your posting and add in the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` so we can see what you've coded in there.

Comment: What OS? What networking system? Anything in `/run` is probably created on the fly. No standard images uses /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0

Comment: I'm running Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) Lite. I believe the wlan0 file exists because wpa-supplicant also runs on startup, and creates the file.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your router at `cc:ce:1e:a7:94:08`? Have you loaded any modules/firmware for your WiFi adapter at: `a6:cb:84:bf:52:3d` (with it's non-standard MAC address)? There is a mention of firmware at https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver - go and read the docs there.

Answer (score 0):

You have failed to explain what networking system but it is probably dhcpcd.

This automatically runs everything necessary. There is no need to attempt to run
etc/wpa_supplicant (as the error message implies)